# Any way to set the timezone used by the rails logger (keeping everything else utc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there any way to set the timezone used by the rails logger while keeping all other time handling utc?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this custom logger: http://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/beautiful-logging-for-ruby-on-rails-3-2/

You could set a custom timezone by doing something like this:

```
def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
  time = time.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```